# Paging sharepoint list using csom

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, paging

Can someone please point me good url to paging sharepoint list using client side object model. I have  this code using javascript but its giving error `unexpected response from server`

```
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" +
        "<ViewFields>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Id'/>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>" +

        "</ViewFields>" +
        "<RowLimit>" + pageSize + "</RowLimit></View>");
    //camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><RowLimit>" + pageSize + "</RowLimit></View>");

    spItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(spItems, 'Include(Name,Id)'); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, success),
        Function.createDelegate(this, fail));
   }
```

So please would be nice if someone give me same approach which i can do in code behind.

Answer (score 3):

I did a Google search on "sharepoint javascript csom paging". The first hit was [Paging in SharePoint JavaScript Client Object Model](http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/08/paging-in-sharepoint-javascript-client.html)

The article contains this code:

```
var listItems;                   // The list of retrieved items.
var query;                       // For paging, reuse the same query object.
var targetList;                  // The list from which to retrieve items.
var clientContext;

function runCode() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
    query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //Specifying the RowLimit will determine how many items will be fetched in one call to the server.
    query.set_viewXml("<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><RowLimit>2</RowLimit></View>");
    listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(listItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var message = "Titles, two at a time:\n";
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        message += "\nTitle=" + listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title")
    }
    alert(message);
    //Gets the id of the last element from the returned collection along with the query.
    var position = listItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition();
    //Position will be null if all the items in the collection are fetched and there are no more items to be fetched.
    if (position != null) {
        //If more items are to be fetched, make a second call to the server and fetch the next group of items.
        query.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);
        listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
        clientContext.load(listItems);
        //Call the same function recursively until all the items in the current criteria are fetched.
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I actually fired up BIWUG CAML Designer and did it instead of lmgtfy

Comment: i want to write this code in code behind so this wont work

Comment: @Happy, th code snippet in your post is JSOM (client side code) and so is the code above

Comment: you see that mine and yours code is same. I was using javascript only but i want to use same in my c# code

Comment: @Happy Google for "SharePoint ListItemCollectionPosition paging" and you'll find a C# code example

Comment: Can you put sample code so i can accept answer